# ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.customuser', but app 'users' isn't installed

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to make an basic Blog application using CRUD operation with the help of Django web framework, I have this code in models.py file of my blog application.

```
`from django.db import models
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 from django.urls import reverse
 # Create your models here.


 class Post(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     body = models.TextField()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse('post-detail', args=(str(self.id)))`
```

And now, when I tried to migrate, I am getting this error saying that "ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'users.customuser', but app 'users' isn't installed."
And because of that, I am not able to see Users link inside the admin account at "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/"

Comment: Are you using a custom User model?

Comment: Yes, I am using Custom User Model. But the thing is I can run this program without error using Windows laptop. However, I am getting this error in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this error happens because our initial migrations are unapplied. Use this command first:

```py
python manage.py migrate
```

After this retry your makemigrations command.

`python manage.py makemigrations`

If the above command runs successfully then again use `python manage.py migrate`  to migrate your tables to database.