# Django ValueError: field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'app.user', but app 'app' doesn't provide model 'user'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124631/valueerror-the-field-admin-logentry-user-was-declared-with-a-lazy-reference-to) but its only answer didn't help:

```
❯ python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
```

Because when I execute `python manage.py migrate` I get the following traceback:

```
❯ python manage.py migrate

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, portfolio, sessions
  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\src\packages\pweb_django\manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\src\packages\pweb_django\manage.py", line 19, in main    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 98, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 236, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 49, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 544, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "C:\Users\user\Projects\personal_website\pweb-venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 615, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))

ValueError: The field admin.LogEntry.user was declared with a lazy reference to 'portfolio.user', but app 'portfolio' doesn't provide model 'user'.
```

Yet, when I check the file `portfolio\models.py` it clearly provides the 'user'-model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    """Dummy class in order to mimic a standard Auth-user.

    Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project
    """
    pass
```

In the related `portfolio\admin.py` - file, the following admin site is being registered:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I would like to understand why this does not work while the other model-class can be found and registered without an issue:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project

admin.site.register(Project)
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens if you ran default auth app migrations and later changed the AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py. You can try following:

```
#comments AUTH_USER_MODEL in the settings.py file so it points to a default User Model

Python manage.py migrate auth zero

#Uncomment AUTH_USER_MODEL='recommend.AuthUser'

Python manage.py migrate auth
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60060092/19255291)

If it's doesn't solve your problems and you are using **Sqlite3** you can:

```
Delete all migration files except __init__.py file.
```